# Como solucionar el error al cargar una imagen en ionic con angular "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin"

Tags: angular, ionic

Estoy intentando cargar una imagen en un proyecto en Ionic con angular pero me tira el siguiente error.

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768

Como puedo solucinar ese error para cargar la imagen sin que la bloquee

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: no se puede, debes agregar una autenticación, o el backend, agregar tu dominio en origin, o mas simple, bajarte los cors y dejar acceso libre